# How to send PURGE method and check response in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, purge

Now I create a project. And try create a unauthenticated cache purge scanner program. I tried this but not work

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os 
import requests
 
with open('new-target.txt', 'rb') as f: 
    L = f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END) 
    
    while f.read(1) != b'\n': 
        f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_CUR) 
         
    a = f.readline().decode()
    
filepath = a

with open(filepath) as fp:
   line = fp.readline()
   cnt = 1
   while line:
       x = "{}".format(line.strip())
       
       resp = requests.purge(x + "/")
       responsee = resp.status_code
       
       if responsee == 200:
           print("\033[1;32;40m [Method - PURGE]      \033[0m 1;31;40m Vulnerable: \033" + x)

       line = fp.readline()
       cnt += 1
```

Gave this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/Masaüstü/Pentesting Tools/PURGE-PUT-Method-Scanner.py", line 23, in 
resp = requests.purge(x + "/")
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'purge'

Answer (score 0):

Traceback which you got seems to be preety straightforwards. Module requests which you use in this case does not have that `purge` attribute, which you are trying to call in line 23.

Please refer to methods listed in documentation:

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/

Comment: Thanks for your reply

But i was know i can't send purge method with requests module and i wonder how can i send purge or else method in python? At curl it's possible with -X parameter but how can i send purge method in python ?